# Adding ScrollViewer in XAML

Tags: windows, xaml, win-universal-app, scrollviewer

I am trying to add a `ScrollViewer` to my page. My page consists of a `Grid` and `GridViewItems`(Tiles). I am wanting to be able to horizontally scroll across my page... But am unable to find where I should place the `ScrollViewer`. Below is my code and where I have placed the `ScrollViewer`:

```
<Grid>
    <GridView  Margin="12,60" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid  Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>

        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="#2A2A2A"
                                  Margin="5"
                                  Height="200"
                                  Width="300">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <GridViewItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="SampleText"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Foreground="White"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Margin="10,10" />
            </Grid>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="SampleText"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Foreground="White"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Margin="10,10" />
            </Grid>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="SampleText"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Foreground="White"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Margin="10,10" />
            </Grid>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="SampleText"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Foreground="White"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Margin="10,10" />
            </Grid>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="SampleText"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Foreground="White"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Margin="10,10" />
            </Grid>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="SampleText"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Foreground="White"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Margin="10,10" />
            </Grid>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="SampleText"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Foreground="White"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Margin="10,10" />
            </Grid>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="SampleText"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       FontSize="18"
                       Foreground="White"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       Margin="10,10" />
            </Grid>
        </GridViewItem>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

This is currently not doing anything.... Can anyone point me in the right direction? What I am wanting to do is be able to scroll horizontally the contents of the page

Comment: Ok so you have a couple issues here. Your panel is a WrapGrid. So with a scrollviewer and Horizontal Scrolling there will be no boundary set to invoke your wrapping without some sort of hard set max width or something. Your other part, you'll need to set your gridview.template with <ScrollViewer><ItemsPresenter/></ScrollViewer> or you can just embed the whole GridView in ScrollViewer since as it sits, each item has a ScrollViewer, but you may want to think about what your overall goal is considering the first issue I mention.

Comment: Could you post an example as a proposed answer with a non--wrapgrid? I am not opposed to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only Horizontal Scroll means just remove your `Orientation` from `ItemseWrapGrid` and change it to like this

```
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <ItemsWrapGrid/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

and set some `Height` to your `GridView` control.

If you want both `Horizontal` and `Vertical` Scroll means change your code Like this

```
 <ScrollViewer>
            <GridView Margin="12,60" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" Height="800">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <ItemsWrapGrid />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Style.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Grid Background="#2A2A2A" Margin="5" Height="200" Width="300">
                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style.Setters>
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <GridViewItem>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="SampleText" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="18"
                                Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10" />
                    </Grid>
                </GridViewItem>
                <GridViewItem>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="SampleText" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="18"
                                Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10" />
                    </Grid>
                </GridViewItem>
            </GridView>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I added you above suggestion, it did add the scroll bar, but now I have 2 scroll bars(side by side)... The only change I made to yours was I changed it from Horizontal to Vertical. Any suggestions?

Comment: you need both horizontal as well as vertical scroll bar or horizontal only?

Answer (score 0):

It should work without ScrollViewer. Add several `GridViewItem`s with sample text and check.

```
 <GridView  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid  Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>

        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="#2A2A2A"
                                      Margin="5"
                                      Height="200"
                                      Width="300">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <GridViewItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="SampleText"
                           FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                           FontWeight="SemiBold"
                           FontSize="18"
                           Foreground="White"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           Margin="10,10" />
            </Grid>
        </GridViewItem>
    </GridView>
```